# How to make state/props available to child components before the child component's constructor executes?

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6

I'm building a real-time financial data app in React and I'm having some issues getting data from state to child components. Part of the issue is I'm pulling the data every few seconds so it's changing often.

My component hierarchy is:

```
<App />
  <Dashboard />
    <Ticker />
      <Gold />
```

In short, I'm running a function that takes the current price of an asset and measures it against the previous closing price for that asset to see if the current price is up or down. Based on that, I want to apply a CSS class, 'price-up' and 'price-down'.

I'm initializing state inside the parent `<App />` component's constructor

```
this.state = {
  goldPrice: '',
  goldUp: null
}
```

Also in the constructor I'm executing the ajax request to grab the price for the first time.

```
this.fetchGoldPrice();
```

I then pass the gold price object to

```
updateGoldPrice()
```

This function takes the object, pulls out current price and last closing price, and sets a boolean, `goldUp`, based on those prices, then sets state.

```
this.setState({ 
  goldPrice: goldPrice,
  goldUp: goldUp
});
```

That all takes place inside the `<App />` component. I then pass props to my other components:

```
<Dashboard goldUp={this.state.goldUp} />
```

And then down to `<Ticker />`

Inside of the `<Ticker />` constructor I'm running some code that pushes on, or splices off, a className from an array of className's, based on if `goldUp` is true or false.

I put a console.log inside of setState() in the `<App />` component and one inside the constructor of the `<Ticker />` component. The ticker component's constructor method is firing before state is actually set inside of App. So when the app initially loads the Ticker component doesn't have the data to render correctly.

[image]

How do I fix this?

I don't think it makes sense to do the array splicing inside of `<App />` before state is even set? Thank you.

Comment: you lost me in _"Also in the constructor I'm executing the ajax request to grab the price for the first time."_. never do ajax request in the `constructor` nor `componentWillMount`! do it in `componentDidMount`

Comment: @rehnirt, oh yes, as @Sag1v said, is it much better do ajax in the `componendDidMount`, this makes sense in server-side rendering

Comment: If I need the data immediately, why is it better to fetch the data in componentDidMount after the render instead of in the constructor before the render? They both seem to work.

Comment: Because `componentDidMount` isn't called on server-side. Nevermind, I think you can don't care about it today.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to check the state of the App in its render method and not to render dashboard while your state is not completed. You can show a Loader at that time

```
render(){
   return (
       <div>
          {
             this.state.goldUp!==null ? (
                  <Dashboard />
             ) : (<Loader />)

          }
       </div>
   );

}
```

Comment: Thank you. This worked. Is this a common practice? Am I doing this the proper way?

Comment: Yes, it is proper way